# bootstrap thumbnail single image slider for small images (or for more number of images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/thumbnail-carousel-single-image-sliding

I am working on above link. It is fine only for 3 images. But if I need more than 3 images to display, that too `col-md-2` images I am getting BLANK space. It is displaying only 3 images.

This is because I need to change javascript, let me the solution for the above question.

[you can have a look at this image, i have changed div size to col-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF6CT.png)

Comment: Can you provide a live preview?

Comment: please repply asap..

Comment: live preview means?? check the above link and in html, just change the col-md-4 to col-md-2, you will get the preview.

Comment: We need live preview we can edit easily without using dev console. JS Fiddle or Codepen would be ideal. You will not get much help here without something we can easily edit.

Comment: you can edit in http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/thumbnail-carousel-single-image-sliding       its not working in fiddle..

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXvqxj

Comment: hey have a look at this code pen..

Comment: this bootstrap thumbnail carousel is for three images, you can't change it. If you want for more images then choose another one

Comment: ok is there any ssimple javasccript gallery? plss post a related working link..

Comment: you can select from here [carousels](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/carousel) and [for four images](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/9009m)

Comment: no i need same UI.. like multiple small images.. and on click of next, only 1 image should move..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change in javaScript like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }

         if (next.next().next().length > 0) {
            next.next().next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
         if (next.next().next().next().length > 0) {
            next.next().next().next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

This will work for 5 images. If you want it for more than 5 images like 6 then add one more `if-else` condition.

```
if (next.next().next().next().next().length > 0) {
        next.next().next().next().next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
```

Because it calculate the length of its siblings.

This is working code for 6 images with div size `col-md-2`